# How to update Android Studio Chipmunk to Giraffe without reinstalling?

Tags: android-studio, installation, updates

When I check for updates in Android Studio, this window opens up:
[view screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7fB8t.png)
But when I click on download, the Android Studio Website opens up in my browser, where one can install the newest version. I was used to updating the application from within the IDE, the button in the window used to say/is supposed to say "Download and restart" and execute the update.

Anyway, I downloaded the newest version from the website and started the installer exe.
The problem is: the setup wizard does not recognize that I already have android studio installed and therefore will not update the existing application but install another one.
Since I don't want any trouble with existing locations and files from the version that I already installed, I canceled the installation.

Can anyone tell me if there is a way to acutally update the version without having to reinstall it?

Answer (score 0):

Check for Updates Again: Sometimes, the initial check for updates might not work correctly. Try going to `Help > Check for Updates` once more to see if the correct update process triggers.

When you run the downloaded installer, it should detect the existing Android Studio installation and provide an option to update it. Make sure that you're using the same installation directory as your current installation to avoid creating multiple copies of Android Studio on your system.

If it doesn't automatically detect the previous version, Backup up and reinstall it. You can do this by going to `File > Export Settings` and saving your settings to a file. This will allow you to restore your preferences and configurations after the update.